# Setting Up Inmemorywebapi URL in angular2

Tags: angular

I have this in-memory-web-api called in-memory-data.service.ts which looks like following.

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
        let users = [
            {name:'shoaib', email:'shoaib2014@namal.edu.pk', father_husband:'M.Iqbal', address:'Chakwal', cnic:'3720102140677'},
            {name:'adil', email:'adil2014@namal.edu.pk', father_husband:'Malik Akil', address:'Chakwal', cnic:'3720102140678'},
            {name:'xyz', email:'xyz@namal.edu.pk', father_husband:'uvw', address:'abc', cnic:'3720102140679'}
        ];
        return users;
    }
}
```

This file is present in a sub folder _services in app folder.How i can setup URL for this api?

Answer (score 2):

By default url will be like (from memory api docs)

```
This in-memory web api service processes an HTTP request and returns an Observable of HTTP Response object in the manner of a RESTy web api. It natively handles URI patterns in the form :base/:collectionName/:id?
```

you can find more detail here

https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

Comment: i have seen this link..But iam not able to understand why my url is not found by server.

I have tried url = /app/_services/in-memory-data.service/users and 
url = /in-memory-data.service/users.
But on both occasions url was not found by server and it gave 404 not found error.

Comment: try using api/users (in your service)
just give this as url and no relative path

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpModule }           from '@angular/http';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

import { InMemoryDataService}     from '../app/yourfilepath';
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   HttpModule,
   InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
   ...
 ],
 ...
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

Comment: import { InMemoryDataService }  from '../app/_services/in-memory-data.service'; what should be the url?

Comment: url=/app/_services/in-memory-data.service/users is not working

Comment: url should be relative `../app/_services/in-memory-data.service`

Comment: still 404 not found :(

Comment: you can even try one thing put the file in app level and change it to `./in-memory-data.service`